# What is the difference between Go Context Value and OpenTracing Baggage Items?

Tags: go, jaeger, opentracing

I want to understand the difference between Context in Go and Baggage Items in OpenTracing. Specifically, their difference to carry data.

From what I have learned, both can carry key-value pairs to their descendants(child contexts / child spans).

In Go's standard library, I can use:

```
func context.WithValue(parent Context, key, val interface{}) Context
```

In OpenTracing, I can use:

```
func SetBaggageItem(restrictedKey, value string) Span
```

Clearly, there are some type restrictions (interface{} and string). Is there anything else should I know?

Under what circumstances should I choose which to carry some key-value pairs?

Comment: The main use of context.Context is for cancelation.

Comment: @Volker Yes, I understand. So I should not use context.Context to pass values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of these have different use-cases.

GoContext is used to define Context type which carries deadlines, cancellation signals, and other **request-scoped** values across API boundaries.

> In Go servers, each incoming request is handled in its own goroutine.
> Request handlers often start additional goroutines to access backends
> such as databases and RPC services. The set of goroutines working on a
> request typically needs access to request-specific values such as the
> identity of the end user, authorization tokens, and the request’s
> deadline

Whereas, OpenTracing framework is used for Distributed tracing. We use distributed tracing to profile monitor applications. The baggage is metadata piggy **backing the request across services**.

```
SERVICE A -> SERVICE B -> SERVICE C
```